# Calling A Method At Specific Time Every Day

Tags: ios, nstimer

My app runs constantly in kiosk mode.  Once every 24 hours at a specific time I need to sync some data from core data to a web service.

I know how to do the sync piece but I don't know how to schedule the app to make the sync call at a specific time each day e.g. at 02:45 am.

Is it possible to do something like this when an app is running constantly?

Comment: Ofcourse its possible. :) I can not specifically say how but it has to be similar to alarm logic where at particular time, it triggers some action.

Comment: @motionpotion just take a look at this link may be you want this http://redth.codes/ios7-recipe-background-fetching/

Comment: @motionpotion : if you got the solution then please share with me...i am trying same task for last many days...help me

Answer (score 4):

Use Local Notifications. Here is a tutorial:http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Hope this helps u to start...

This as well:

[Local Notifications](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-local-notifications/?search_index=1)

[Background Tasks](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-tasks/?search_index=2)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Local Notifications?

Comment: What if user didn't give the permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out thanks to prompts from @lakesh.  Posting solution in the case it helps somebody because I found NSNotification examples very difficult to understand at first.

In my main view controller I added the following method:

```
- (void)scheduleNotification
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

[components setDay: day];
[components setMonth: month];
[components setYear: year];
[components setHour: 02];
[components setMinute: 45];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

notif.fireDate = dateToFire;
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

This sets a fire date for the notification of today at 02:45 am and recurs daily.

In viewDidLoad in my view controller I call the above method:

```
[self scheduleNotification];
```

In the appdelegate I do the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{   
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    //call your method that you want to do something in your app
}
```

Comment: if you do this, will the user see a blank message?

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution is just to set `NSTimer` to check current date every minute (or every second, for example). If the current date is greater then required, then fire the method and update the required date.