# Perform task once a day

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How would you go about performing a task once day?

In my case, I need to check if contact information has changed. (Contact information is in a big CSV file on amazon S3).

One way I thought is to save last date checked into a file then read it back from it when the application starts. But I feel that's so amateur.

Should I use core data? (Tested it a long while ago, just popped in my head).

Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Use a local notification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run code once a day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10903568), [Calling a method at specific time every day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16653991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on your AppDelegate.

An easy representation for saving;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YourDateHere" forKey:@"lastAmazonCheckDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] syncronize];
```

And retrieving;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastAmazonCheckDate"];
```

With NSUserDefaults you can save the last time you checked for your list.

Comment: You forgot to synchronize, but figure out, ty.

Comment: yeah your right, syncronize added.

Answer (score 0):

_lastUpdate is a NSDate object

```
_lastUpdate = [NSDate date];

- (NSDate*)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view
{
    return _lastUpdate;
}
```

so like this you can check and update your task everyday i think you know this as you mentioned but i also have the only solution for now.