# Pop to root view at midnight if app is still running

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attempting to return the user to the first screen of the application if the app is still up and running at midnight and things are about to transition to a new day.

I am using

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
```

to detect this change but there are some issues...

First, there were random triggers occurring at 9:30 or 10:45 causing the app to kick back to the main screen too soon.  I understand there are other factors to trigger this method like daylight savings and messages from the carrier.  But neither of those applied to the day it was triggering too early.

So I added in this code to manually check the clock hour and minutes checking to see if the time on the device was between 11:58 PM and 12:02 AM.

```
      //Get current time
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];

if ((hour>=23 && minute > 58) || (hour == 0 && minute < 2))
{
   //return to main screen
}
```

This worked fine in testing by manually adjusting the device clock.  However, I left the device over night, woke up the next morning, and it never triggered.

Why is this method so finicky? and is there a better way to handle what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Left it overnight how? Connected to Xcode? Why aren't you using the `currentCalendar`?

Comment: Just left the app running but the device idle.  not connected to xcode.

Comment: Your app may have been suspended? Apple docs say: "f your app is currently suspended, this message is queued until your app returns to the foreground, at which point it is delivered. If multiple time changes occur, only the most recent one is delivered. "

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel that may of been exactly the issue.  Multiple timers triggered and the most recent didn't fall into the if condition thus it never backed the user out.  So knowing this, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: There does not seem to be an easy way to have an app wake up periodically either. You would have to allow it to run in the background and have it on some sort of light load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I did the following.

1. When the application comes back into the foreground I check the time then, and if a new day has passed, I log them out.
2. In the case the user is in-app during the cross-over, I added a check during a background poll that runs every 4 minutes to check for data, and if a new day has passed, log them out.

Answer (score 0):

You're complaining about this method being unreliable, and to think of it (note that I didn't know the existence of this method as of 10 minutes ago), you could use a completly different way.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099247/3603502) I understand that you can schedule actions (through notifications) and you would, instead of detect when midnight is there, schedule a notification at midnight.
Your method that pops to root would listen to that specific notification, maybe check it's payload to make sure of a few things (that's really up to you), and if the tests passes, because you assume it's been sent at midnight, you can pop.

The only thing I'm truly unsure of but that I advise you to test is if the notification is sent when the app is in background/killed.

Either way, you can easily check the UIApplicationState before sending the notification and react accordingly, as well as the current date and time, so therefore, when the user comes back from background or re-starts the app or anything, you know what to load.

From scratch, without much brainstorming, here is how I understand it

- User is using the app now => Notification is sent & read, with foreground state => pop to root
- User has app in background => (Unsure about notification) => either way, set something in the NSUserDefaults to load the root VC, in -`appWillEnterBackground`
- User has app killed, do the same as the previous step.

And this pretty much got all your situations covered with one method and one notification. Now you just have to test it out to make sure I haven't ignored something important.

Comment: I was also going to suggest using a local notification. These are always sent when scheduled and are accurate in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pop to root view controller you can use:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application.keyWindow.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

About midnight firing I would check something in the way of scheduling a [silent local notification](http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications).

Comment: Push notifications and silent notifications are too unreliable for what I need.  This needs to be all the time, work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1) When an app starts, create a new timer which is set for midnight using `NSTimer`. You may be able to do all this in step 3) in one place to cover start and resume. Use:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFireDate:(NSDate *)date
                        interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
                          target:(id)target
                        selector:(SEL)aSelector
                        userInfo:(id)userInfo
                         repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

Use a selector which is part of your app delegate instance.

If the timer fires, send a local notification and record the date sent.

When the timer fires, create a new timer for midnight on this new day.

2) Use the app delegate call `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` to detect the app going to the background.

When this happens, remove the timer and record the date removed.

3) Use the app delegate call `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` to detect the application has resumed running in the foreground.

Reinstate a timer for midnight. As noted 1) could perhaps be done in this function if it is called on start which i think it is.

Check the date the last notification was sent if any). If its not nil, the app was running before. If the now date is a day on from the old date, send a local notification and record the date.

Summary:

So I would use suspend/resume notification to 100% reliably track midnight rollover and use NSTimer to reliably tell you it is midnight if your app is running.

Use local notifications to publish the event which can be picked up by your view controllers.